# Уходят неизвестные запросы из браузера

Tags: вирусы

В последнее время (недавно скачал подозрительную программу) стал замечать, что в браузере периодически на секунду промелькивает плашка в углу об ожидании ответа страницы, зашел в инструменты разработчика - **уходят POST и GET запросы на следующие адреса**:

- https://cdnmc.global-cache.online/cfg_7d.json?t=2023-03-24T18:5
- https://m.youtube.com/static/r/8d5aaa4c/scheduler.vflset/scheduler.js?subtype=view&udid=aaaab047f82e49fc&id=1&burl=https%3A%2F%2Fm.youtube.com%2Fstatic%2Fr%2F8d5aaa4c%2Fscheduler.vflset%2Fscheduler.js&config=eyJhY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsInN0YXJ0IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9tLnlvdXR1YmUuY29tL3N0YXRpYy9yLzhkNWFhYTRjL3NjaGVkdWxlci52ZmxzZXQvc2NoZWR1bGVyLmpzIiwiY291bnQiOjEsInByb2QiOnRydWUsInZpZXdfdHlwZSI6MSwibmVlZF9hbGwiOmZhbHNlLCJuZWVkX2F1dGgiOnRydWUsIm5lZWRfZnVsbCI6ZmFsc2UsInRpbWVyIjo2MCwid29ya2VyIjoxOCwibmVlZF9saWtlIjp0cnVlLCJzZXRfbGlrZSI6dHJ1ZSwibmVlZF91c2VyIjpmYWxzZSwibmVlZF90b3VjaCI6dHJ1ZSwidGltZSI6NjAwMDAsImhpc3RvcnkiOnRydWV9
- https://service.gstatic-cache.com/youlist.php?worker=18&uid=SgJANVxRFKpzFvNG/A7g2TUEomwmVK2CGh&rand=0.3327564567069925
- https://tl.ytlogs.ru/timesince
- https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0

Много данных содержится в payload и ответах. Может быть сталкивались с таким, что это может быть?

Comment: кто инициатор запросов?

Comment: @Grundy, если запросы с моего компьютера, то инициатор я, но запросы происходят автоматически, никакие страницы не открываются, только json передаётся

Comment: Имелась ввиду колонка `initiator` на вкладе "Сеть" в инструментах разработчика